# Prevent drag event leaking through element border

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm doing drag-and-drop with nested drop zones. At the bottom of the z-order is a large div (called a "chapter" in my application) which is a drop zone. Within the chapter div is a table (built in CSS) in which each table cell div is also a drop zone. Inside one of the cells is a draggable element. When I drag this element from one cell to another, sometimes the drag event fires on the underlying chapter div. This interferes with the user operation, making it very hard for the user to drop the dragged element exactly where they want it.

This only happens when the cell divs have a border, and so I suspect that if the browser happens to generate a drag event at the exact moment when the mouse is over the border (dragging between cells) then the event is not captured by the cell, and instead falls through to the chapter.

I'm using Angular with Swimlane `ngx-dnd` https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-dnd/. This seems to absorb all the native browser drag events, replacing them with its own custom events which are fired only on the nominated drop zone divs. I tried to intercept the native events in a new div between the cell and the chapter, where I could discard them, but this doesn't work because my code never sees the native events.

How can I prevent the drag event leaking through the border onto the underlying chapter div? Or, indeed, have I mis-diagnosed the problem?

Here's what it looks like when I start to drag:

[image]

And then when I drag over the border between the two cells, the `over` event fires on the chapter div, and `ngx-dnd` shows a preview of the dragged content where it would be dropped onto the chapter. This preview pushes the table downwards, leaving the mouse pointing over the table, not the cell.

[image]

Here's some minimal HTML that exhibits the problem:

```
<div id="test">
 <div class="test-chapter">
  <div ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragChapter($event)" (over)="OverChapter($event)">
   <div class="test-table-container">
    <div class="test-table" (drag)="DragTable($event)" (over)="OverTable($event)">
     <div style="display:contents">
      <div class="test-row-container">
       <div class="test-row" (drag)="DragRow($event)" (over)="OverRow($event)">
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div style="display:contents">
      <div class="test-row-container">
       <div class="test-row" (drag)="DragRow($event)" (over)="OverRow($event)">
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
           <div class="test-content">
            <div class="test-content-class">
             <p>drag me</p>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div style="display:contents">
      <div class="test-row-container">
       <div class="test-row" (drag)="DragRow($event)" (over)="OverRow($event)">
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:contents">
         <div class="test-cell-container">
          <div class="test-cell" ngxDroppable="test-dropzone" (drag)="DragCell($event)" (over)="OverCell($event)">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.test-chapter {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: white;
}

.test-table-container 
{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 30px;
  cursor: grab;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #bce9b3;
}

.test-table
{
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.test-row-container {
  min-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  display: table-row-group;
}

.test-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.test-cell-container
{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  background-color: #b6cdf7;
}

.test-cell
{
  min-height: 20px;
}

.test-content
{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f59fb9;
}

.test-content-class
{
  min-height: 20px;
  border: dashed thin #8b8b8b;
  color: black;
}
```

And the Javascript for debugging:

```
DragChapter(event)
{
  console.log('drag chapter');
}

OverChapter(event)
{
  console.log('over chapter');
}

DragTable(event)
{
  console.log('drag table');
}

OverTable(event)
{
  console.log('over table');
}

DragCell(event)
{
  console.log('drag cell');
}

OverCell(event)
{
  console.log('over cell');
}
```

Comment: I don't claim to fully understand the scenario (showing us some code would help!) but if the problem arises only in relation to borders have you tried box-sizing: border-box - to force the border 'within' the element?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of box-sizing: border-box. I had already tried that, and it made no difference. In fact it was already set by the Bootstrap theme we use.

Comment: Since you asked for code I've updated the question. In preparing some minimal sample code I've been able to eliminate the problem by removing some divs, but unfortunately those divs seem to be necessary for normal layout. But at least it's a new avenue of investigation, so thanks for prodding me.

Comment: It seems that the `dragover` event is indeed passing through the border, meaning that the element doesn't receive the event when the mouse is on the border. I've eliminated this problem by inserting a borderless div underneath the top dropzone to catch and kill the rogue event. (Only if its phase is `AT_TARGET` so as not to prevent bubbling.) Unfortunately this fix only works in my pure HTML test, and not in my `ngx-dnd` stuff, so it looks like I'll have to ditch `ngx-dnd` and do my own drag-and-drop by hand.

Comment: I'm using gridstackjs and am having the same issue, did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Professorofprogramming To the table cell div I attached a listener to discard the `dragover` event if it originated on the cell: `if(event.eventPhase == Event.AT_TARGET) event.stopImmediatePropagation();`